In concentric circles Triangle formed from intersection of a line making 45 degree with x axis where inner circle meets x axis to outer circle
I have two concentric circles one of radius 5 cm and outer one of 10 cm, their centers being 0,0 I want to calculate P B and H of the triangle formed by intersection of a line on outer circle making an angle of 45 Degree with x axis from the point where inner circle intersect the x axis the perpendicular is drawn from the intersection at outer circle to x axis. I have attached the image for reference.[image for circles]


This problem is amenable to coordinate-based solutions. The outer circle has equation $x^2+y^2=10^2$, and a line at $45^\circ$ from $(5,0)$ has slope $1$ and form $1=\frac{y-0}{x-5} \Rightarrow y=x-5$. Substituting for $y$ leads to $x=\frac{5 \pm 5\sqrt{7}}{2} \approx 9.1144$. So the triangle has coordinates $(5,0),(9.11,0),(9.11,4.11)$, equal sides of length $4.11$, and hypotenuse of approximately $5.81$.

Thanks man I really needed the coordinates for programming a layout function, but can you give me a general formula for this my math has become a little weak since I have left my high school 6 years ago

I may not be a man, man. But here's a formula: 1) Figure out your point on the inner circle, 2) Write the equation of the line with the slope you want and solve for y, 3) write the equation of the outer circle and substitute in the y from the prior step, 4) this forms a quadratic equation, to which you can apply the quadratic formula to solve for the x where the line and circle intersect, this gives the second point. 5) Use this x to solve for the y in step 2, which yields the 3rd point.
